# Find the Homology Groups of The Klein Bottle With 2 Distinct Points Identified

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I need to find the homology groups of the Klein Bottle with 2 distinct points identified. I struggle with setting problems up where points are removed or identified. Once I have the correct picture, I can figure out the problem, but drawing the right $\Delta$-complex is difficult. This is my attempt at drawing it. https://ibb.co/t3LPrKm My idea was to create an extra vertex $w$ to represent an extra point which is a $0$-simplex and identify it with the standard point $v$ through the edge $c$. I do not know if this is a valid way of solving this problem though. Any help and feedback would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your idea that the two points can be identifying them by linking them by a new edge is correct, but you need to know a bit about homotopy extension properties to justify it. It would be helpful if you told us what methods for calculating homology groups you know about.

Comment: I am primarily only familiar with calculating homology via methods of $\Delta$-complex and simplicial homology. I have only had a couple of lectures and read a bit of Hatcher's Algebraic topology on $\Delta$-complexes and simplicial homology.

Comment: In that case, adding a new edge isn't an option: you need a $\Delta$-complex that is homeomorphic to the identification space. You can get that with 4 triangles, 6 edges and 2 points, by modifying Hatcher's diagram for $K$ so that the 4 corner points that are already identified are also identified with the centre point of the square and adding edges from the top left and bottom right corners to the centre to satisfy the requirements of a $\Delta$-complex.

Comment: The picture you linked seems correct to me, except that $w$ should also be labeled $v$. Isn’t this precisely what @RobArthan just described?

Comment: @TedShifrin: also the new edges should not all be labelled $c$ (I think the OP was intending $c$ to be like a string joining the two identified points rather than as distinct internal edges splitting existing faces up so that you get a valid $\Delta$-complex.)

Comment: Joke comment: why would a person _want_ to stick two points on a Klein bottle together? :)

Comment: @paulgarrett: if you knew what I have on my to-do list tomorrow, you'd be clamouring to doing stuff with that gum Klein bottle.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$$\partial{A}=0$$
$$\partial e_1=0, \partial e_2=0, \partial e_3=0, \partial e_4=0$$
$$\partial f_1=-e_2+e_3+e_4-e_1$$ $$\partial f_2=-e_2+e_1+e_3+e_4$$
Since $\partial (f_2+f_1)=2(-e_2+e_3+e_4)\neq 0$ and $\partial (f_2-f_1)=2e_1\neq 0$, we have $$H_0=\Bbb Z, H_1=\Bbb Z^2\oplus\Bbb Z_2^2, H_2=0.$$

I expected one extra $\Bbb Z$ coming. I am not sure about $H_1.$